# To by pass the SUSPENDED AWS accounts using AWS Organizations API

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-organizations

I was trying to write the code where it will pass the list of accounts within AWS Organizations which are `SUSPENDED` and will print the logic output for the `ACTIVE` accounts. The code snippet is:

```
def get_accounts(role_arn) -> list:
    '''Appends all the accounts listed in operations into ACCOUNTS'''
    accounts = []
    creds = get_aws_key_and_token(role_arn)
    sess = session.Session(
        aws_access_key_id=creds['AccessKeyId'],
        aws_secret_access_key=creds['SecretAccessKey'],
        aws_session_token=creds['SessionToken']
    )
    accounts = {}
    org = sess.client('organizations')
    paginator = org.get_paginator('list_accounts')
    page_iterator = paginator.paginate()
    for page in page_iterator:
        for acct in page['Accounts']:
            accounts[acct['Id']] = acct['Name']            
    return accounts
```

Can someone please help me to add that functionality?

Thanks

Comment: How can you identify a 'Suspended' account?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I am looking for the way where the code will run for the active accounts and suspended accounts will bypass.

Comment: Yes, but what do you mean by a 'Suspended' account, and how will your code detect such an account? Do you have one in your organization? Is it identifiable?

Comment: Suspended account means the account which got deleted/deactivated. Though under the list_accounts API of AWS organizations we can find the status of account i.e. Active/Suspended but I am not able to write the code where it will print the logic only for Active accounts and by pass the Suspended accounts

Answer (score 0):

The [`list_accounts()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/organizations.html#Organizations.Client.list_accounts) documentation shows the output as:

```json
{
    'Accounts': [
        {
            'Id': 'string',
            'Arn': 'string',
            'Email': 'string',
            'Name': 'string',
            'Status': 'ACTIVE'|'SUSPENDED',
            'JoinedMethod': 'INVITED'|'CREATED',
            'JoinedTimestamp': datetime(2015, 1, 1)
        },
    ],
    'NextToken': 'string'
}
```

Therefore, you could use:

```py
    for page in page_iterator:
        for acct in page['Accounts']:
            if acct['Status'] == 'ACTIVE':    # <---- This line added
                accounts[acct['Id']] = acct['Name']
```

Comment: Did you use the above `if` statement to selectively add accounts to your `accounts[]` dictionary? That is, only add if the status is `ACTIVE`.

Comment: I have edited my answer to suggest where you might add the line.

Answer (score 0):

So this piece of code is ignoring the suspended accounts which are part of the AWS organizations and only running against the ACTIVE accounts. The good thing about this is it will be used as a module for any other AWS service.

```
def get_accounts(role_arn) -> list:
    '''Appends all the accounts listed in operations into ACCOUNTS'''
    accounts = []
    creds = get_aws_key_and_token(role_arn)
    sess = session.Session(
        aws_access_key_id=creds['AccessKeyId'],
        aws_secret_access_key=creds['SecretAccessKey'],
        aws_session_token=creds['SessionToken']
    )
    accounts = {}
    org = sess.client('organizations')
    paginator = org.get_paginator('list_accounts')
    page_iterator = paginator.paginate()
    for page in page_iterator:
        for acct in page['Accounts']:
            if acct['Status'] == 'ACTIVE':
                accounts[acct['Id']] = acct['Name']
    return accounts
```